# Why is my Thread not cycling?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a problem where my Thread does not cycle and I am not sure why. It runs the run method once and then stops. Here is my code.

```
public class LifeFrame extends JApplet{

    private Scanner scan;
    public FramePanel framePanel = new FramePanel();
    private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton button1 = new JButton("Start");
    private JButton button2 = new JButton("Stop");
    private JButton button3 = new JButton("Reset");
    public ImageIcon onTemp = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("squareOn.png"));
    public ImageIcon offTemp = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("squareOff.png"));
    public Image lifeOn = onTemp.getImage();
    public Image lifeOff = offTemp.getImage();
    public boolean[][] lifeCheck = new boolean[20][20];
    public boolean[][] lifeHolder = new boolean[20][20];
    public boolean run = false;
    private Thread animator;

    public void init(){
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("life100.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine().trim());
        for(int i = 0; i < temp; i++)
            lifeHolder[Integer.parseInt(scan.next().trim())-1][Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine().trim())-1] = true;

        framePanel.setSize(700,800);

        button1.setSize(100,60);
        button2.setSize(100,60);
        button3.setSize(100,60);
        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
        button1.addActionListener(handler);
        button2.addActionListener(handler);
        button3.addActionListener(handler);
        buttonPanel.setSize(300,60);
        buttonPanel.add(button1);
        buttonPanel.add(button2);
        buttonPanel.add(button3);
        buttonPanel.setBackground(new Color(71,68,68));

        add(framePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        startThread();
        framePanel.repaint();
    }

    public void startThread(){
        animator = new Thread(framePanel);
        animator.start();
    }

    public class FramePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{
        public FramePanel(){
            this.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 20));
        }

        public void run(){

            long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

            beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            while(run){
                cycle();

                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
                sleep = 500 - timeDiff;

                if (sleep < 0)
                    sleep = 2;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleep);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Sleep Interrupted");
                }

                beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }

        public void cycle(){
            int neighbors = 0;
            for(int row = 0; row < lifeHolder.length; row++)
                for( int col = 0; col < lifeHolder[row].length; col++)
                    lifeCheck[row][col] = lifeHolder[row][col];

            for(int row = 0; row < lifeHolder.length; row++){
                for( int col = 0; col < lifeHolder[row].length; col++){
                    for(int r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++){
                        for(int c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++){
                            if(r >= 0 && c >= 0 && r < lifeHolder.length && c < lifeCheck[row].length)
                                if(lifeHolder[r][c])
                                    neighbors++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(lifeHolder[row][col]){
                        neighbors--;
                        if(neighbors < 2 || neighbors > 3)
                            lifeCheck[row][col] = false;
                    }else{
                        if(neighbors == 3)
                            lifeCheck[row][col] = true;
                    }
                    neighbors = 0;
                }
            }
            for(int row = 0; row < lifeHolder.length; row++)
                for( int col = 0; col < lifeHolder[row].length; col++)
                    lifeHolder[row][col] = lifeCheck[row][col];

            repaint();
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g){
            for(int r = 0; r < 20; r++)
                for(int r1 = 0; r1 < 20; r1++){
                    if(lifeHolder[r][r1]){
                        g.drawImage(lifeOn, r1*20 + 3, r*20 + 29, 20, 20, framePanel);
                    }else
                        g.drawImage(lifeOff, r1*20 + 3, r*20 + 29, 20, 20, framePanel);
                }
        }
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if(event.getSource().equals(button1)){
                run = true;
                System.out.println(run);
            }
                if(event.getSource().equals(button2)){
                    run = false;
                    System.out.println(run);
                }else{
                    //reset
                }   
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any chance it is throwing an exception?  I'd wrap your run in a `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`.

Answer (score 3):

You define `run` as `false`.

You launch the thread, the thread starts executing the `run` method, and (as the variable `run` is `false`) it ends.

Later, maybe the user may click a button and set the variable `run` as `true`. But by the time the user can click something, your thread has exited a long time ago.

Use an infinite loop, use `run` to check must do something or if it must sleep. Set the thread at daemon so the JVM kills it when the last non-daemon thread ends.

Answer (score 2):

Because the variable `run` is defined as `false` at startup

Answer (score 1):

When you start the thread, the `run` variable is false. The thread goes through the `run` method once, fails the loop condition, and falls out of the bottom of the method and terminates.

By the time `run` is set to true by the `ButtonHandler`, the thread is long dead.

Rather than trying to manage your own thread, i suggest you look into using [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), which is designed specifically to let you trigger work in a background thread from a GUI event.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning you set

```
public boolean run = false;
```

and then do

```
while(run){
[...]
}
```